# Nativescript Greensock issue - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TweenLite'

Tags: ios, nativescript, pixi.js, gsap

I would love to use webview with PixiJS and Greensock (GSAP) in my Nativescript app. I have no problem to add TweenMax.min.js but when I have more GSAP files like for instance plugins/PixiPlugin.min.js - on `$ tns run ios` I have something like this:

```
ERROR in ./assets/game/js/gsap/plugins/PixiPlugin.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TweenLite' in '/systemfolder/app/assets/game/js/gsap/plugins'
 @ ./assets/game/js/gsap/plugins/PixiPlugin.min.js 287:153-177
 @ . sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)(?<!\.\/\btests\b\/.*?)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$
 @ ./app.js
```

and I stuck at this point so app does not run. Any clue?

Comment: Can you show your file structure, how you have organised these files? Have you included these files in your bundle, you might have to update webpack config for that.

Comment: No worries Manoj, I've resolved the issue upgrading GSAP code base to version 3 (released at the end of November '19). https://greensock.com/?ct=1581772388

Comment: To use GSAP 3 plugins you do indeed have to load GSAP 3, not GSAP 1 or 2. See [GSAP's installation page](https://greensock.com/install) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Migration from Greensock 2 to GSAP 3 resolved my issue. https://greensock.com/

Comment: I've built in 2 days this simple iOS prototype with GSAP and NativeScript. This is just a proof of simple game concept - GSAP is great and supports PixiJS. NativeScript makes sense - https://youtu.be/MQfFzYLhhe0